# Time conversion error (colon)

Tags: vba, excel, format, messagebox

I want to display a time value with VBA, so I load the value with this command:

`MsgBox Worksheets("table").Cells(1, 1)`

The value of the field is: `8:00`, but the MsgBox shows: `0,3333333...`

Does anyone know, why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message box is showing the unformatted value. Each day to Excel is one unit and 8 hours is 1/3rd of one day. If you want it to display as `08:00` try:

```
MsgBox Format(Worksheets("table").Cells(1, 1), "hh:mm")
```